# How to arrange the data on RecycleView in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-studio

I would like to use RecycleView for displaying my array of data.

This is my Adapater class which is setting data on view.

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder>{

        private Context context;
        private List<Pojo> dataList;

        public DataAdapter(Context context, List<Pojo> dataList) {
            this.context = context;
            this.dataList = dataList;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main,parent,false);
            return new MyViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.categoryTV.setText(dataList.get(position).getGameName());
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {

            return dataList.size();
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

            public TextView categoryTV;

            public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                categoryTV = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:id="@+id/rellayout"
    tools:context="com.acknotech.kiran.retrofit_second.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is MainActivity..

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private DataAdapter dataAdapter;
    private List<Pojo> dataArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
    }

    private void initViews(){
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        loadJSON();
    }

    private void loadJSON(){
        dataArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("my url").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();
        AllGamesAPI requestInterface=retrofit.create(AllGamesAPI.class);

        Call<List<Pojo>> call= requestInterface.getJSON();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Pojo>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Pojo>> call, Response<List<Pojo>> response) {
                dataArrayList = response.body();
                dataAdapter=new DataAdapter(getApplicationContext(),dataArrayList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Pojo>> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.e("Error",t.getMessage());
            }

        });
    }
}
```

When i try to execute it always printing only one item at a time but in dataList i have 11 items.

How to use RecyclerView to get all items in a page?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: check more options with the response.body() function

Comment: I'm getting 11 items to DataAdapter... my doubt is how to handle that 11 items in adapter over xml data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't inflate the activities layout in `onCreateViewHolder`, but instead inflate a layout for only one item (e.g. `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`, or a custom one). This layout should not use `match_parent` for the height of items.

Comment: When i try to replace the layout what you suggested my app is crashing and in log.. ::

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
This error i have seen in log. I think this is because i'm returning that view  and it is used by MyViewHolder as a parent view.

Comment: You also have to adjust the textview id. (simple_list_item_1 uses android.R.id.text1)

Comment: Give me an idea how to do the same example for POST with username and password as a parameters.

Comment: I'm not used to Retrofit. Open a new question if you have a different problem.

Comment: A Huge and Humble Thank You.